# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')

Tags: node.js, server, axios, multer

I have been working on a project and I want to upload PDF to it. For handling POST request in the backend, I used multer library for uploading files. I tested this `http://localhost:3000/schedule/upload` endpoint in the postman, and it is working fine, apparently while requesting this same endpoint from Front-end it is giving this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')`.
I searched all over the internet and I couldn't able to find a single solution to this problem. So, if someone has any idea what is going wrong here, Please tell me. It will be a great help to me.

**Client-side Code**

```
const saveFile = async () => {

        let file = document.getElementById("fileInp").files[0];
        console.log('inside  ' + file)
        let formdata = new FormData();
        
        formdata.append("schedule", file);
        

        const config = {
            url : '/schedule/upload',
            method : 'post',
            data :  {
                filename : 'schedule',
                formdata
            },
            headers : {
                Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`,
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }

        try {
           const res = await axios(config);
           console.log(res.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        return;
    }
```

**Server-side Code**

```
const upload = multer({
    limits : 1000000
})

fileRouter.post("/schedule/upload",auth,upload.single("schedule"),async(req,res)=>{
    await File.findOneAndUpdate({fileName : "schedule"},{fileName : req.body.filename, file : req.file.buffer},{upsert : true}).exec();
    res.status(200).send("Schedule uploaded");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the file is not parsed, which means the request is not correct.
Change `data` property to include only `formData`, no need to include filename, it's already within `formData`, and `multipart` header is also not needed.

Try changing `config` variable to this:

```
const config = {
    url: '/schedule/upload',
    method: 'post',
    data: formdata,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
}
```